# Update method not working

Tags: c#, mongodb

Trying to play around with MongoDB, wrote a update method which would take a name as a parameter and if it exists, it replaces it with Oneyl.

```
public void updateTry(string name) {
            var mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
            var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("football");
            var coll = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Footballers");

            var documents = coll.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < documents.Count(); i++) {
                if (documents[i].ContainsValue(name)) {
                    documents[i].Set("Name", "Oneyl");
                }
            }
        }
```

Im trying to use a simple c# structure to achieve my goal, but any mongodb input is welcomed, such as queries, but please if you decide to offer some queries, explain them. 
Not sure if Im using the Set method correctly. "Name" is the actual field in the database.

Answer (score 0):

you can use code like to the following and also to be perfect i need to know you document format or structure to give you example to be able to update your documents

```
       MongoClient _client = new MongoClient();
        _database = _client.GetDatabase("Store");
        var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Customers");
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", new BsonObjectId(new ObjectId(_id)));
        var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("CompanyName", CompanyName_str)
            .Set("ContactName", ContactName_str)
            .Set("ContactTitle", ContactTitle_str)
            .Set("Address", Address_str)
            .Set("City", City_str)
            .Set("Region", Region_str)
            .Set("PostalCode", PostalCode_str)
            .Set("Country", Country_str)
            .Set("Phone", Phone_str);
        try
        {
            collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
            IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
        }
        catch (MongoWriteException mwx)
        {
            if (mwx.WriteError.Category == ServerErrorCategory.DuplicateKey)
            {
                // mwx.WriteError.Message contains the duplicate key error message
            }
        }
```